# Read Query String value with . in Web API C#

Tags: c#, webapi

please suggest controller method in c# web api to read the value of query string from http://xxxxxxxx.xxx/api/test?product.one=soft&product.two=hardware

please make a note without . parameter name not possible

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Request.Query** to read everything in the query parameters

[image]